# Can we call DOM(javascript) event listener in a function in React js(Not in useEffect or ComponentDidMount)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener

I am calling an event listener inside a function in React hooks - **not using useEffect** and removing it inside the same function which is called when event fires, is there anything wrong with that?
Example : -

```
const handleMyEvent = () => {
...
...
const element = document.querySelector('myDiv');
  if(element){
     element.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseEvent);
  }
}

const handleMouseEvent = e => {
...  setting my some state 
...
const element = document.querySelector('myDiv');
element.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseEvent);
}
```

is there something wrong with code or logic, please let me know because **it is working fine**.

Comment: it depends on the context and the overall outcome that you want to achieve. Please, provide some more code so the context is more clear

Comment: Basically, I am creating a select option functionality. A case where I am stuck in b/w is when a user opens that dropdown and hovering on one of the options with the mouse and starts using the keydown to use it, when he goes to the last option ie visible in dropdown(since it has scrollbar) and use the key down again. Mouseover event selects the option where mouse was left. Since, I am using a mouseover event I am maintaining a state to update the mouse coordinate but it won't update once you reach the element since mouseover event did not fire. To avoid it, I am adding an event on key function

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the once option to have a listener act only once, then remove itself.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters

Example:

```
element.addEventListener('eventname', (ev) => {
    console.log("event is captured only once.");
    // do more stuff...   
}, { once: true });
```

Comment: that's really helpful, but can I add an event listener in the function as I have shown in the example? Because I always see inside.useEffect in react-hooks.